# Modis MOD11A1 band math expression

Tags: remote-sensing, modis, envi, band

I am trying to calculate the temperature of MOD11A1 and I can't find the expression of band math. How the expression `temp < 273` could be written at band math?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a binary layer wth values before or under 273, you can use the build mask tools (basic tools > Masking > build mask)

in IDL, you can use the following relational operators

```
gt for >
ge for >=
eq for ==
le for <=
lt for <
```

Comment: thank you so much for you useful answer. Another related question, how we can divide two bands?

Comment: in order to make your question usefull for other, please don't ask questions in comment but ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "B1 lt 273" where B1 is a LST band.

Comment: please include an explanation to back up your answer